# how to create url column dataframe using two column values in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have following dataframe.

```
company,compid,secid
a,a1,a2
b,b1,b2
```

I need output like following format

```
company,compid,secid,url
a,a1,a2,http://www.cssss.com/companydetails.aspx?compid=a1&secid=a2
b,b1,b2,http://www.cssss.com/companydetails.aspx?compid=b1&secid=b2
```

how to add column values in url column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df['url'] = 'http://www.cssss.com/companydetails.aspx?compid=' +
             df.compid + '&secid=' + df.secid
print (df)
  company compid secid                                                url
0       a     a1    a2  http://www.cssss.com/companydetails.aspx?compi...
1       b     b1    b2  http://www.cssss.com/companydetails.aspx?compi...
```

I change `url` for testing:

```
df['url'] = 'http:aaa.aspx?compid=' + df.compid + '&secid=' + df.secid
print (df)
  company compid secid                               url
0       a     a1    a2  http:aaa.aspx?compid=a1&secid=a2
1       b     b1    b2  http:aaa.aspx?compid=b1&secid=b2
```

If `dtypes` of columns `compid` and `secid` is `int`, cast to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['url'] = 'http:aaa.aspx?compid='+df.compid.astype(str)+'&secid='+df.secid.astype(str)
print (df)
  company compid secid                               url
0       a     a1    a2  http:aaa.aspx?compid=a1&secid=a2
1       b     b1    b2  http:aaa.aspx?compid=b1&secid=b2
```

EDIT by comment:

If [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) of columns `compid` and `secid` contains `NaN` it can be empty string:

```
#code before
data3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='company', how='outer') 

print (data3)
  company compid secid
0       a     a1    a2
1       b     b1    b2
2       a     a1   NaN
3       b    NaN   NaN

data3.loc[~data3[['compid','secid']].isnull().any(1), 'url'] = 
'http:aaa.aspx?compid=' + data3.compid.astype(str) + '&secid=' + data3.secid.astype(str)

data3.fillna('', inplace=True)
print (data3)

  company compid secid                               url
0       a     a1    a2  http:aaa.aspx?compid=a1&secid=a2
1       b     b1    b2  http:aaa.aspx?compid=b1&secid=b2
2       a     a1                                        
3       b
```